# Where can I find different plans of a SPARQL query?

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, sql-execution-plan

I want to see as many plans of a SPARQL query as possible. That is, I don't want the optimized plan only, but all the possible plans, or at least some plans, like p1,p2,p3,p4 of a query q1. Using Apache Jena or any other such tool, is it possible? I want to try all the query plans of a query and want to see the execution time.

Comment: Afaik Jena doesn't produce multiple plans, but a single plan based on reorder rules and heuristics as well as plenty of transformation rules, e.g. filter push and the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@UninformedUser is quite right in their comment that Jena **ONLY** generates a single plan by default.

However, it is theoretically possible to find all the possible plans Jena could generate by toggling on/off all the optimiser flags that control which optimisations are used.

In [`OptimizerStd`](https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/f7e1674016a9375e6ab86d1ddc7b125266ec0c44/jena-arq/src/main/java/org/apache/jena/sparql/algebra/optimize/OptimizerStd.java) each possible optimisation is enabled/disabled by a context symbol.  So you could generate `Context` objects with different combinations of the configuration symbols enabled/disabled and create instances of the optimiser with different `Context`'s and see how the resulting algebra differs.  There are a lot of possible optimisations so you may not want to consider every possible combination of flags, maybe start by experimenting with some more obvious ones like `ARQ.optFilterPlacement` and `ARQ.optIndexJoinStrategy`.  You may want to explore the code further to review the actual `Transform` implementations to understand the potential optimisation each flag is controlling.

Note that you will first need to parse your SPARQL string into a Jena `Query` object and then compile it into algebra using [`Algebra.compile(Query)`](https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/f7e1674016a9375e6ab86d1ddc7b125266ec0c44/jena-arq/src/main/java/org/apache/jena/sparql/algebra/Algebra.java#L70).  If you're interesting in the quad form of the algebra you also need [`Algebra.toQuadForm(Op)`](https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/f7e1674016a9375e6ab86d1ddc7b125266ec0c44/jena-arq/src/main/java/org/apache/jena/sparql/algebra/Algebra.java#L84)